# Connecting android app with web page that has no api

Tags: android, web-applications, mobile-application

I want to make android application that connects to simple forum page that has no api or mobile view.

I want to create customized offline buttons and windows and i do not want simple android web view. How i can connect the UI of the page with the app since there is no api?

Answer (score 0):

Well since there is now official api you will probably need to get all the data you need from the html returned by the site itself. I'd recommend you check out [the volley library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/)
It's worth mentioning that you might be able to find an undocumented api if you look for calls from javascript on that site (ajax) or if theres already a non-web-version you could try to do a Man in the middle. However since this seems to be a rather basic forum its unlikely that this exists.

Answer (score -1):

If it is page to app communication, you need to use a `JavascriptInterface`. If you need an app to page communication, you need to use `loadUrl("javascript:")`.